# Why should the support of a random variable be closed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am looking for an intuition regarding why the support of a random variable is **closed**.
I read for example that the support of an n-dimensional random variable as the "smallest **closed** subset of $R^n$ of probability one". Or that the support is the "closure" of the range of values of the random variable. What is the intuition behind **closed**?

Comment: The support if the law $\mu$ of a random variable is by definition the smallest closed set that has full mass. Equivalently, it is the complement of the union of all open sets that have mass zero. The random variable itself is not the interesting object, but its probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why we define it as closed. I understand why it is the smallest, and why it needs to have full mass, but not why it should be closed. What happens if it is not closed?

Comment: This is probably in analogy to the support of a function. Remember that a function $f$ from a topological space (think of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual distance between points) to $\mathbb{R}$. One wishes to see where $f$ is in effect different from zero. One can take the carrier $\{(x\in X: f(x)\neq0\}$, but there are points that are in the boundary between the carrier and points where $f$ vanishes, so it is convenient to take the closure. Similarly, a measure $\mu$ may be concentrated in a set $A$, that is $\mu(A)=1$ and so $\mu$ does not see the outside of $A$ (it gives it measure zero ).

Comment: But $A$ may be very "porous", For a point to be in the support, $\mu$ has  to feel it. SO one may say that a point $x$ is in the support of a probability distribution  $\mu$ if for any open neighborhood  $B_x$ of $x$, $\mu(B_x)>0$. The set of such points $S_\mu$ can be easily proven to be a closed set. Now, if your topological space $X$ (again think of real values random variables) has some nice properties (separability, as in the reals where rational numbers are dense), it turns out that $\mu(S_\mu)=1$ (i.e. $S_\mu$ hs full mass). If $X$ is weird, that may not happen and pathologies occur.

Answer (score 0):

Example:  What is the support of Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,1]$?  (In the OP language: What is the support of a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$?)
Note for each singleton we have $\lambda\big(\{x\}\big) = 0$.  So "the intersection of all measurable sets of measure $1$" is $\varnothing$.  Not a useful concept.  But "the intersection of all closed sets of measure $1$" is $[0,1]$.